# How to fix a Unity 2d object to the edge of a screen?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game in Unity, where Objects are spawned at the awake state into a grid type pattern. I want the first object to spawn on the left edge of the screen and the others to follow. 
And I have got it working more or less correctly, when I test in unity's built in game tester. I even try it in different resolutions and it still looks ok.
However, when I build the project and then test it, the objects are all off camera and it looks nothing like the preview build.
I have tried many various suggestions offered by what I could find on google, and they don't seem to be any better 
The way I am instantiating the first object is to first get the X value of the edge of the screen by using 
`int ix = -(Camera.main.scaledPixelWidth / 2)`


And then I will add half the width of the object, using

```
var renderer = clone.GetComponent<Renderer>();
float width = renderer.bounds.size.x / 2f;
ix += (int) width;
```

I've also tried using the screen.width and Camera.main.PixelWidth values, and all are the same... They look fine in all the aspect ratios on the built in game preview for Unity, but when I do a build for Windows or WebGL the objects are starting offscreen and only the last few will render on screen.

Does any one have any suggestions for a way to get objects to render exactly on the edge no matter the resolution? 

I realise it may work better if the objects are manually laid out, but the objects need to be rendered at the start of the level as the idea is to reuse one scene and load in assets depending on a parsed xml file, as it's a puzzle game and I want users to be able to create their own puzzles as well ultimately.

Comment: Are you using a Canvas? You know that this value will be in pixel space not necessarily in worldspace units

Comment: Yes I am using a canvas, and it is set to the main camera and scales with the screen size. The UI elements are rendering correctly. 
So with the worldspace units, would I need to use the camera ViewportToWorldPoint function somehow?

Comment: **If** you need the coordinates in world space then it would be `ScreenToWorldPoint` .. otherwise: Is simply using a [HorizontalLayoutGroup](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-HorizontalLayoutGroup.html) and spawning your objects as child of it an option? With this you would need no script at all but just configure the things correctly in the RectTransforms

Comment: Ok so I'll see if I can figure out how to use ScreenToWorldPoint then.
I thought about a layout group, but the problem is the number of elements will be variable, and the size of the objects might vary, so it could look strange. But if I can't come right with the screen to world point function, I'll try the group instead. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Just tried the group, and it breaks the ability to drag and drop the elements, which I need, so it will have to be the screentoworldpoint option I think, or something similar

Comment: just set the Anchors in the canvas correctly ...

Answer (score 1):

Since you already are speaking of UI elements inside a `Canvas` all **you need to do is set the anchors and pivot points correctly.**

Either do this already in your prefab

[image]

or later via code e.g.

```
var rectTransform = clone.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
var anchorsVector = new Vector2(0,0.5f);
rectTransform.pivot = anchorsVector;
rectTransform.anchorMin = anchorsVector;
rectTransform.acnhorMax = anchorsVector;
```

now all you need to do is set this object to a position `x=0` to "attach" it to the left edge. With this current setting `y=0` means centered vertically. You can of course change this to your needs.

```
rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(0, 0);
```

---

As in this little demo

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    [ContextMenu("Test")]
    private void Test()
    {
        var rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        var anchorsVector = new Vector2(0,0.5f);
        rectTransform.pivot = anchorsVector;
        rectTransform.anchorMin = anchorsVector;
        rectTransform.anchorMax = anchorsVector;

        rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(0, 0);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok so I think that will work well for Text and other UI elements. How would it handle normal gameobjects without a RectTransform?

Comment: If they are in a Canvas simply add the RectTransform to them and do the same

Comment: OK the effect is not quite right, the box colliders get shifted away. I am sure it can be fixed easily enough, but I have found using Screen to WorldPoint does seem to do what I want, as the bottom left corner is always 0,0 and I can set my starting X position to zero and work that way.  So thank you for your help regardless.